# How to load html page from extension resources on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

Hi guys i'm trying to load abc.html page that is on root folder of my extension that i am testing on firefox also i'm new to extension building.

when using in chrome i used to simply make a link like this
"chrome-extension://avtrpplasdaikjninbgasfrhemnfmaefff/abc.html"

and it used to open but i'm stuck in firefox also i already tried using

resource://abc.html

and it didn't work.neither i came across any satisfactory results on google.
thanks in advance.

Comment: In Firefox you should use [browser.runtime.getURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getURL) because the id is [random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: ok but what is the syntax or path that i should follow

Comment: I don't understand. You can see examples in both links.